# PL/SQL difference between DEFAULT and assignment operator

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm newbie in PL/SQL and this question might seem to be 'childish' so I'm sorry in advance, but Google didn't help me at all...

Is there any difference between following procedures?

```
Procedure p1(a Number DEFAULT 0) Is
Begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(a);
End;


Procedure p2(a Number := 0) Is
Begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(a);
End;
```

I have checked them, so when I call both of them without args the output is `0`, but I'm not sure if there are any side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CHDFADII)

> You can use the keyword DEFAULT instead of the assignment operator to
>   initialize variables. You can also use DEFAULT to initialize
>   subprogram parameters, cursor parameters, and fields in a user-defined
>   record.
>
> Use DEFAULT for variables that have a typical value. Use the
>   assignment operator for variables (such as counters and accumulators)
>   that have no typical value.

```
DECLARE
    blood_type CHAR DEFAULT 'O';         -- Same as blood_type CHAR := 'O';
    hours_worked    INTEGER DEFAULT 40;  -- Typical value
    employee_count  INTEGER := 0;        -- No typical value

  BEGIN
    NULL;
  END;
  /
```

So I guess internally is the same.

Comment: Hmm, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot

Comment: No guesswork required, they are the same. Although I don't understand the "No typical value" comment, that line defaults `employee_count` to `0`, there's literally no difference between `default` and `:=` in this context.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I guess it goes under "Use the assignment operator for variables (such as counters and accumulators)". I actually always used `DEFAULT` on parameters and the operator to initialize variables.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp On one hand `employee_count` can be changed by hiring/firing somebody, and it's normal situation, and on other - there is always 40 hours in a work week, changes in this value is not normal.

Comment: They're the same. Don't mix them, your artificial distinction will be inscrutable to future developers.

Comment: @LibertyPaul when talking about variables always use assigment only, e.g. `a integer := 0;`. If it's constant use still assigment, e.g. `a constant integer := 0;`. Typical value vs. no typical value just makes no sense in real life.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look to the documentation of the latest Oracle release (12c R1) at the moment of writing. You explicitly ask for subprogram parameters so let's take that first.

[Default Values for IN Subprogram Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS666):

> When you declare a formal IN parameter, you can specify a default value for it. A formal parameter with a default value is called an optional parameter, because its corresponding actual parameter is optional in a subprogram invocation. If the actual parameter is omitted, then the invocation assigns the default value to the formal parameter.

The documentation doesn't mention `default` keyword but it still works. Example (in 12c R1):

```
declare
  function f1(a in number)           return number is begin return a; end;
  function f2(a in number := 2)      return number is begin return a; end;
  function f3(a in number default 3) return number is begin return a; end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(f1(1));
  dbms_output.put_line(f2);
  dbms_output.put_line(f3);
end;
/
```

Prints 1, 2, 3 as expected.

However as it's not mentioned in the authorative documentation I discourage the use of `default` keyword in this context.

Other interesting context is [Initial Values of Variables and Constants](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS173):

> To specify the initial value, use either the assignment operator (:=) or the keyword DEFAULT, followed by an expression.

And that's the only time `default` keyword is mentioned. All documentation examples use assigment only.

**Conclusion**

Technically `default` keyword and assigment are the same and work in both contextes, but only assigment is promoted in the documentation. I think Oracle is effectively deprecating the `default` keyword in this context and thus I won't recommend the use of it in new PL/SQL code. Assigment operator makes the same job with zero fuss.